# Parsing Complexed XML file using Coldfusion

Tags: xml, coldfusion, xml-parsing, coldfusion-9

I am parsing an XML file with vehicle data and specifications. I am having problems looping over certain nodes to get multiple values. Here is some code I have working.

```
<cffile action="READ" file="c:\websites\db-utils\sample.xml" variable="xmlData">

<cfscript> 
    myxmldoc = XmlParse(xmlData); 
    modelNumber = XmlSearch(myxmldoc, "//basic_data/model_number"); 
    modelNumber = modelNumber[1].XmlText;

    enginename = XmlSearch(myxmldoc, "//engines/engine"); 
    enginename = enginename[1].XmlAttributes.name;

    camtype = XmlSearch(myxmldoc, "//engines/engine/cam_type"); 
    camtype = camtype[1].XmlText;

    transmissionname = XmlSearch(myxmldoc, "//transmissions/transmission"); 
    transmissionname = transmissionname[1].XmlAttributes.name;
</cfscript>
<cfoutput>
    Model Number: #modelNumber# <br />
    Engine: #enginename#<br>
    Cam: #camtype#<br>
    Trans: #transmissionname#<br>
</cfoutput>
```

The XML I am have problem with is when I get deeper and need to loop over nodes. Her is a snippet of the XML.

```
<decoded_data>
    <decoder_messages></decoder_messages>
        <query_responses>
            <query_response identifier="1" transaction_id="CC969FDA9C2B546EEC0A8036F19C7A8543A7148E">
                <query_error></query_error>
                    <us_market_data>
                        <us_styles count="1">
                            <style name="XLE 4dr Sedan" vehicle_id="400892838" complete="Y" market="US Light-Duty" fleet="N">
                                <basic_data></basic_data>
                                <pricing></pricing>
                                <engines></engines>
                                <transmissions></transmissions>
                                <specifications>
                                    <category name="Drive Type"><specification name="Drive Type">FWD</specification></category>
                                    <category name="Fuel Tanks"><specification name="Fuel Tank 1 Capacity (Gallons)">17</specification></category>
                                    <category name="Interior Dimensions">
                                        <specification name="Cargo Volume">15.4</specification>
                                        <specification name="Passenger Volume">102.7</specification>
                                    </category>
                                    <category name="Measurements of Size and Shape">
                                        <specification name="Front Track Width">62.4</specification>
                                        <specification name="Ground Clearance">6.1</specification>
                                        <specification name="Height">57.9</specification>
                                        <specification name="Length">190.9</specification>
                                        <specification name="Rear Track Width">62</specification>
                                        <specification name="Wheelbase">109.3</specification>
                                        <specification name="Width">71.7</specification>
                                    </category>
```

This is where is am having difficulty finding how to loop over the specifications and the categories within them. Also getting both the 'name' and the actual 'specification'. I am kinda going the right direction with this code:

```
<cfset specNodes = xmlSearch(myxmldoc,'//specifications/category')>
<cfoutput>
<cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(specNodes)#" index="i">
   <cfset specXML = xmlparse(specNodes[i])>
    #specXML#<br>   
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

But I am not quite there... any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that as follows:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(specNodes)#" index="i">

    <h3>#specNodes[i].XmlAttributes.name#</h3>  

    <cfset specChildren = specNodes[i].specification />

    <cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(specChildren)#" index="j">

        <br/>#specChildren[j].XmlAttributes.name# = #specChildren[j].XmlText#

    </cfloop>   

</cfloop>
```

Which gives you:

```
**Drive Type**

Drive Type = FWD

**Fuel Tanks**

Fuel Tank 1 Capacity (Gallons) = 17

**Interior Dimensions**

Cargo Volume = 15.4
Passenger Volume = 102.7

**Measurements of Size and Shape**

Front Track Width = 62.4
Ground Clearance = 6.1
Height = 57.9
Length = 190.9
Rear Track Width = 62
Wheelbase = 109.3
Width = 71.7
```

Answer (score 2):

> This is where is am having difficulty finding how to loop over the
>   specifications and the categories within them.

You can try this:

```
<!--- Get all category nodes under specifications. This will return an array --->
<cfset specNodes = xmlSearch(trim(xml), "//specifications/category")>

<!--- loop over array containing category nodes --->
<cfoutput>
  <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(specNodes)#" index="catCounter">

    <!--- Get Name of the category --->
    Category Name : #specNodes[catCounter].xmlAttributes.name#<br />
    Specifications: <br />

    <!--- Loop over specifications of current category --->
    <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(specNodes[catCounter].specification)#" index="specCounter">

        <!--- Get specification name --->
        Specification Name: #specNodes[catCounter].specification[specCounter].xmlAttributes.name#<br />

        <!--- Get specification value --->
        Specification Value: #specNodes[catCounter].specification[specCounter].xmlText#<br />
    </cfloop>
    <br /><br />
  </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

This will give following as output:

```
Category Name : Drive Type
Specifications: 
Specification Name: Drive Type
Specification Value: FWD


Category Name : Fuel Tanks
Specifications: 
Specification Name: Fuel Tank 1 Capacity (Gallons)
Specification Value: 17


Category Name : Interior Dimensions
Specifications: 
Specification Name: Cargo Volume
Specification Value: 15.4
Specification Name: Passenger Volume
Specification Value: 102.7


Category Name : Measurements of Size and Shape
Specifications: 
Specification Name: Front Track Width
Specification Value: 62.4
Specification Name: Ground Clearance
Specification Value: 6.1
Specification Name: Height
Specification Value: 57.9
Specification Name: Length
Specification Value: 190.9
Specification Name: Rear Track Width
Specification Value: 62
Specification Name: Wheelbase
Specification Value: 109.3
Specification Name: Width
Specification Value: 71.7
```